# query builder create update statements only if input value is not null

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, query-builder

I am working on my java application and use cassandra as the data store with datastax java driver. I am using Querybuilder to construct my queries.

The update query is tricky because I want to change a field only if the input value is not null.

Example:

```
Statement st = QueryBuilder.
    update("repo_info").
    with(QueryBuilder.set("team", repo.getTeam())).
    and(QueryBuilder.set("author", repo.getAuthor())).
    and(QueryBuilder.set("git_project_url", repo.getGitProjectUrl())).
    where(QueryBuilder.eq("name", name)).ifExists();
```

So here I want to say update team only if repo.getTeam()(or the input) is not null  otherwise leave it the way it was. Can someone please help here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**NOT NULL** property only works for primary key in Cassandra. Before you bind information with the **st** Query-builder, you should check  **repo.getTeam() !=NULL**. This is one of easiest way.

For Example:

```
PreparedStatement st = QueryBuilder.
    update("repo_info").
    with(QueryBuilder.set("team", QueryBuilder.bindMarker())).
    and(QueryBuilder.set("author", QueryBuilder.bindMarker())).
    and(QueryBuilder.set("git_project_url", QueryBuilder.bindMarker())).
    where(QueryBuilder.eq("name", QueryBuilder.bindMarker())).ifExists();

if(repo.getTeam !=NULL){    
    session.execute(st.bind(repo.getTeam(),repo.getAuthor(),repo.getGitProjectUrl(),name));          
}
```